# Inline navigation with hashbang pages

Tags: ajax, url, hash, navigation, hashbang

In the past, I used to rely on hash for inline navigation, for example:

```
http://url?Category=a&item=3#Paragrah1
```

(Pointing to Paragraph1 within the `http://url?Category=a&item=3` page)

With the widespread use of ajax, the hash tag has switched to a different purpose, allowing page refresh without full page reload. For example:

```
http://url#!Category=a&item=3
http://url#!Category=a&item=4 (the page switches to item 4, no full page reload)
```

My question: how can I make inline navigation work in such pages? To take the above example, how can I point to Paragraph1 in the `http://url#!Category=a&item=4` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) instead. Then you can use the hash for scrolling again.

Comment: Unfortunately the application is already built around #!, I have to live with it and add inline navigation. Also, would the HTML5 history API without #! avoid a full page reload when switching from item 3 to item 4?

Comment: Yes, you would get a [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate) event.

Comment: I am marking this as answer, as it seems like the go forward choice. Unfortunately it is not an option in my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the hash `#` for **both** webapp page navigation and also for moving to a specific element on a specific page, then you'll need to handle the scrolling yourself.

javascript provides: [`window.scroll(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scroll).

In your example, when you handle the URL `http://url#!Category=a&item=4`, you'll need to do a `window.scroll` using coordinates that cause `Paragraph1` to move to the right place on the page, i.e. the top. You'll need to adjust these coordinates anytime the page layout changes.

Comment: Well, Paragraph1 is just one instance. I would expect my inline navigation to allow navigation within the page. There's also a Paragraph2, Paragraph3, etc.